# How to remove spacing between html div elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an 8th Wall Web app but this is more of a css question. So I have these html elements appear on my screen where their style is z-index: 10 (this is a css requirement for html elements to appear via 8th wall web). these elements are like this:

```css
/*the css for box-* are like so:*/
.box-*{
    background-color: red; 
    transform: rotate(-70deg);
    width: 60%;
    height: 20%;
   }
    #scrolling-container{
       z-index: 10;
       position: absolute;
       display: flex;
       top: 38%;
   }
    
    #button-collections{
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       overflow: hidden;
       height: 200px;
       padding-top: 120px;
   }
```

```html
 <div id="scrolling-container">
          <div id="button-collections">
              <div id="box-all"><img id="all-button" src="buttons/btn-all.png"></div>
              <div id="box-seremban"><img id="btn-seremban" src="buttons/btn-seremban.png"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

but because of the rotation the result looks like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKk6T.jpg . How do i get rid of that space between the elements?

Comment: you can use `margin-left: -100px` for example on the right div

Answer (score -1):

Remove `top:38%;` element in `scrolling_container` and remove `padding_top:120px;` element in `#button_collection`

Comment: Please do mention the reason for your suggestion in the answer as well.